# Converting DB-stored EMF file to BMP/JPG to add on SSRS Report

Tags: sql, image, reporting-services, type-conversion

I am working with a SQL database that stores an EMF file as a BLOB. I need to display these images on an SSRS report, but it does not support EMF format on images. I was planning on adding a custom VB code to the report to do this conversion (potentially using System.Drawing .NET assembly), but I am not very familiar on how to do it.

Has anybody done it before and that can share a bit on how to proceed?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: See here for example in csharp. You can combine Csharp and VB in the same report, I am pretty sure: https://github.com/KeesCBakker/KeesTalksTech-Utility-Pack/blob/master/KeesTalksTech-Utility-Pack/KeesTalksTech.Utilities/Graphics/MetafileUtility.cs

Comment: Hi Ben! thanks for the help, I will take a look on that!